# MVC Jquery - button click - getting error on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using mvc6 I am redirecting to another view on a button click and its dependent on a MVC model value which is a bool.

I have looked up a number of question/answers but none that I have found address this issue for me..

Currently I am getting the error: ReferenceError: Model is not defined which means my model is not defined.. Model.Activity is always either false or true but it doesnt like the line..

Further, I am unsure as to how to redirect to another page correctly - in my case I have hardcoded the route.. is this correct or is there a better way?

here is the code.

```
<script>
$("#Activity").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (Model.Activity) {
        window.location.href = "/UserAdmin/Delete/@Model.UserId";
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "/UserAdmin/ChangeActiveSetting/@Model.UserId";
    }
});
```

How do I get this working correctly?

Comment: You need to make AJAX call

Comment: I guess you mean `if (@Model.Activity)` if you wanting to refer to the model used in the view

Comment: Yep did that and got an error on the "else" - ")" expected..

Comment: What error? But why are you doing this. Why not in the view just use `@if (Model.Activity) { @Html.ActionLink(....) } else { @Html.ActionLink(...) }` (no javascript necessary)

Comment: Hi Stephen.. forgive my being obtuse but how would you use an actionlink with a button?

Comment: Just style the link to look like a button if that's what you want

Comment: Used this: @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" }) and it worked... How do I stick a Glyphicon in the button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111692/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-si2030).

Answer (score 0):

If it's boolean you could use `if('@Model.Activity'=='True')`

Answer (score 0):

I am using MVC6 so it would be good to use the available taghelpers in this latest offering. Thanks to @stephen-Muecke I have found the anchor tag can be styled to whatever you want and in my case it was a button... here is what I ended up doing:

```
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.UserId" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a>
```

alot simpler than using jquery and cleaner.